# Add a dropdown toggle only if a condition is fullfiled

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

There is a list of elements created by this:

```
<td>
    <span >{{rows.values}} <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span>
</td>
```

I want that if rows.values has a value greater than 0 to have a dropdown toggle.

My try so far looks like:

```
<td>
    <span >{{rows.values}} <i class="fas fa-caret-down dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" dropdown-toggle></i></span>
</td>

<ul ng-class="rows.values ? dropdown-toggle: ''" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
</ul>
```

but it doesn't do anything.

**LATER EDIT:**

After the suggestions received my code looks like:

```
<td>
    <span >{{rows.values}} <i class="fas fa-caret-down dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" dropdown-toggle></i></span>
</td>
<ul ng-class="{'dropdown-toggle': rows.values}" role="toggle">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
 </ul>
```

but still does not do anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use [AngularUI dropdown directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!dropdown).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add single quotes for values:

```
<ul ng-class="rows.values ? 'dropdown-menu' : ''" role="menu">
<!--------------------------^-------------^
```

Or the other way to do is:

```
<ul ng-class="{'dropdown-menu': rows.values}" role="menu">
```

Comment: corrected that typo but still not working. nothing happens when I click on it

Comment: @LeoMessi Did you check the other version? Try the second way.

Comment: I edited my question, still not working. Should be a problem because it is a toggle and not a menu? I want it to be a toggle

Answer (score 0):

try this.. Use as an expression

```
<td>
      <span >{{rows.values}} <i class="fas fa-caret-down dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></i></span>
</td>

 <ul class="dropdown-menu {{rows.values>0?'':'ele-show'}}">
   <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
</ul>
```

and give a custom style as

```
.ele-show{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: use it same way as given in the answer. see the changes made for span element and ul. And make a click on the bottom tip of the caret

Comment: still not working. there is no toggle or drop-down visible wherever I click. thanks for your help, I will try a different approach maybe

Comment: @LeoMessi  Have you include `bootstrap.min.js`. issue may with the `row.values` also